# Empty lambda capture still shadows outer scope?

Tags: c++11, lambda, gcc-warning

An empty [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) capture list `[]` creates a plain function without a closure object. Why, then, given this example:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  auto _foo = [] (int argc) {
      return argc - 1;
  };
  return _foo(argc);
}
```

does gcc (4.8.5 and 5.4.0) warn that the `argc` of the lambda shadows the `argc` variable of the outer scope?

```
In lambda function:
warning: declaration of ‘int argc’ shadows a parameter [-Wshadow]
     auto _foo = [] (int argc) {
                             ^
note: shadowed declaration is here
 int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
              ^
```

After all, there is no outer/surrounding closure state that could be shadowed.

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning.  The code within the lambda could confuse readers about which variable is being used.

The warning is not about bad behavior, just unreadable code, and the fact it is a non-capturing lambda doesn't really make the code more readable.

The rules for shadowing variables in an inner scope are just as clear for the rules for a non-capturing lambda and a parameter with the same name, and the warning exists for the same reason.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this. A warning ought to be about potential problems, like a signed with unsigned integer comparison. If readability is of concern here then it warrants *at most* a note. Declaring a function with the same argument names doesn't cause a warning either.

Comment: @jens shadowing a varaible does not cause any actual problem.  It is well defined in what it does.  The code no longer looks like it does what it does unless you notice the shadowing, which is why there is a warning.

Comment: I agree with the shadowing in principle. What I am saying is that with an empty closure `[]` there is no outer `argc` that could possibly be shadowed. If the closure would contain the outer `argc` then yes, the parameter would--perhaps unintended--shadow in which case a warning would be warranted. The above code is a pure function *without* closure context and thus *without* anything that could be shadowed.

Comment: Using the same variable name for a different thing is not only completely superfluous - any other name would be fine in the lambda - it also is a foolish habit to ever start. I am glad there is a warning, but you can switch it off if you prefer to not see it. - to be more clear, nothing keeps you legally from naming all your sons 'Adam'; although most parents would consider this a foolish idea.

Comment: @Aganju If I write a handful of functions that operate on integers, then it is most common to name all the arguments with the same name, e.g. `x` or some other arithmetic name. It is very common to name iterators `it` and to hand them around as such. I am not operating in SSA where I need to invent a new variable name for every variable.